# Migrating MySQL database from Amazon RDS to Microsoft Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to find some suggestions on migrating our MySql database from Amazon AWS - Relational Database Service (RDS) to Microsoft Azure. Google search didn't yield any relevant resource as yet.

Could somebody point me to the correct documentation or the right approach to achieve this?

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. That said, what, specifically, are you running into issues with? You should post this type of question to ServerFault, as it's not programming-related.

Comment: Other than the links mentioned in the answer below, you can also have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manibindra/2016/05/03/how-to-migrate-mysql-database-from-aws-rds-to-azure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would perform an export of MySQL DB first. Get the structure and data out. MySQL support on Azure comes in 2 flavors.

1: using a partner/3rd party called Clear DB. You can utilize the Azure portal to create your DB but it will be hosted by Clear DB. Here is an article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/

2: Roll your own VM with MySQL on it. Stand up a Linux VM and install MySQL. Be sure to open endpoints so you can access it. Here is another article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/